# How to run through column and only execute if status not sent

Tags: google-apps-script

I think I'm almost there but I'm having difficulty with forEach.
I need only to send email if the status is not sent , but my code ignores that column and send to everyone again and again.

Here is my full code:

```
function emailPDF(pdf) {
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  DriveApp.getFiles();

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url");
  const responseTab = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  const email = responseTab.getRange(2, 2).getValue() || ''   
  const subject = 'Year Rota';
  const body = "ROTA";

  // Again, the URL to your spreadsheet but now with "/export" at the end
  // Change it to the link of your spreadsheet, but leave the "/export"
  const url = 'url';

  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf
    '&size=letter' + // paper size letter / You can use A4 or legal
    '&portrait=false' + // orientation portal, use false for landscape
    '&fitw=true' + // fit to page width false, to get the actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=false' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid=1897395809'; // the sheet's Id. Change it to your sheet ID.
  // You can find the sheet ID in the link bar. 
  // Select the sheet that you want to print and check the link,
  // the gid number of the sheet is on the end of your link.
  
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  var lastRow = responseTab.getLastRow();
  var status = responseTab.getRange('F2:F' + lastRow).getValues();
    
    //Utilities.sleep(500)
   status.forEach((row,ind) => {
    if(row[6] !== "SENT") {
  // Send the PDF file as an attachement 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: "ROTA" + ".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
   
        }]
    })
    responseTab.getRange(ind + 2 , 6).setValue('SENT');
    }
   })
}
```

How to make sure that it only sends email when the status is not sent.?
Probably it's an easy solution , but I spend few hours already on it and couldn't find anything.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: About `but my code ignores that column and send to everyone again and again.`, in this case, how about checking the value of `row[6]` again? Unfortunately, I cannot know the value of `status` in your script. So, I cannot know the column of `row[6]`. I apologize for this.

Comment: Status is "SENT"  as its sets the value after sending

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Status is "SENT" as its sets the value after sending`, when you check the value of `row[6]`, again, in your script, even when `row[6]` is `SENT`, `row[6] !== "SENT"` is true. Is my understanding correct? If I misunderstood your reply, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, it's just ignores the if statement and sends again to all recipients

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your question, I'm worried that the checking column might be different between your expected column and the actual column. In your current situation, those are the same. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I added full code in here maybe it will be better. By theory it should check column F and if the the status is not equal to SENT then only send the email.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your added script, `status` is from `var status = responseTab.getRange('F2:F' + lastRow).getValues();`. In this case, `status` has only one column. But, you are trying to retrieve the value from column "F" at `row[6]`. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. In this case, please modify `if(row[6] !== "SENT") {` to `if(row[0] !== "SENT") {` and test it again.

Comment: It worked! I feel so dumb now, it was such a simple thing.. Thank you very much for this!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works!

```
function emailPDF(pdf) {
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  DriveApp.getFiles();

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("your url");
  const responseTab = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  const email = responseTab.getRange(2, 2).getValue() || ''   
  const subject = 'Year Rota';
  const body = "ROTA";

  // Again, the URL to your spreadsheet but now with "/export" at the end
  // Change it to the link of your spreadsheet, but leave the "/export"
  const url = 'your url/export?';

  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf
    '&size=letter' + // paper size letter / You can use A4 or legal
    '&portrait=false' + // orientation portal, use false for landscape
    '&fitw=true' + // fit to page width false, to get the actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=false' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid=1897395809'; // the sheet's Id. Change it to your sheet ID.
  // You can find the sheet ID in the link bar. 
  // Select the sheet that you want to print and check the link,
  // the gid number of the sheet is on the end of your link.
  
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  var lastRow = responseTab.getLastRow();
  var status = responseTab.getRange('F2:F' + lastRow).getValues();
    
   status.forEach((row,ind) => {
    if(row[0] !== "SENT") {
  // Send the PDF file as an attachement 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: "ROTA" + ".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
   
        }]
    })
    responseTab.getRange(ind + 2 , 6).setValue('SENT');
    }
   })
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.